# find divs in layers (z-index) above another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have transparent divs that can potentially overlap. They can be positioned in "z order" either by explicit CSS `z-order` or default DOM ordering.
According to style specification there are many combinations of DOM ordering, z-index and `display` style that all influence the resulting effective z position of an element.

How can I find all elements that are above (or below) a given reference object, no relying on simple explicit z-index but according to more general styling rules ?

The focus of my question is only on the z-ordering. By "find" I mean, having a (javascript / jquery) algorithm to select or iterate of the elements above/below.

*notes*: Looking for documentation, I think

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

is a little better to read than

https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

It would be best if one could inquire the "rendering engine" directly somehow - after all clicking at a given x-y-position is directly triggering the top element (at that place) - so the information is already present somewhere ... !?

Comment: Describe "find all elements"? How do you want to find them - JS/developer tools? It's too broad to answer

Comment: Can you give some example code, prefferably some HTML, CSS and JS to make things a bit more clearer?

Comment: Loop through all visible Elements of the page. All Elements before the Current with a lower or equal z-index are before, the rest is after ...

Comment: @Wolfgang: the complication is that z-index is not always set. So one has to first determine, if the current element has z-index set, then everything without is behind - if it's not set , everyone with z-index is in front (except negative z-index ...?) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

this is how you find all overlapping elements, but I am not sure how to order them by z-index. as you said there are many options influencing z-index order. You will need a huge code to do this. not sure about performance as you will need to loop all element few times.

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
            var div = $(this);
            $('body').find('*').each(function() {
                if($(this).width() > 0 && $(this).height() > 0) {
                    if((($(this).offset().left <= div.offset().left && $(this).offset().left+$(this).width() >= div.offset().left)
                        || ($(this).offset().left < div.offset().left+div.width() && $(this).offset().left > div.offset().left))
                        && (($(this).offset().top <= div.offset().top && $(this).offset().top+$(this).height() >= div.offset().top)
                        || ($(this).offset().top < div.offset().top+div.height() && $(this).offset().top > div.offset().top)
                        )) {
                        console.log($(this));
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: change return false to return true if you do not want to block other underlaying events

Comment: Thanks - for x-y this gives me the needed ideas.  You really think regarding `z ordering` multiple visits of elements are necessary.  From my edited question: "It would be best if one could inquire the "rendering engine" directly somehow - after all clicking at a given x-y-position is directly triggering the top element (at that place) - so the information is already present somewhere ... !?"